# Are Snaps installed system wide, or per user?

Tags: software-installation, snap

Are Snaps installed system wide, or are they only installed for the user who is logged in, and installing them? on Ubuntu 18.04?

I don't see any option like Flatpak's `--user` to install Snaps for a single user. And what is the command to install a Snap for a single user?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Installed snaps are available to all users.

Comment: Yes, even if you are able to run `snap install` without sudo, it still installs snaps system-wide.

Comment: Snap packages aren't installed with non-root. The "snap install" command simply tells snapd to install a package, and snapd is running as root and installs the packages in `/snap/`.

Comment: @AliRazmdideh That doesn't have anything to do with snapd. You are misunderstanding how it works. It's the same as not needing sudo to install a package when you install it from the gnome-software app, rather than from the command line. You're just requesting a system service to install it. The fact is that root is still required, and the packages are still installed in the same way.